# join same table with multiple columns and get the latest record with user data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i have two tables named **users** and **message**, I want to join both tables and get the last message from each user's conversation with user name.

I want last message by timestamp between two users whether it is **from_id** or **to_id**, and similarly, want last message from every user from which I had any conversation.

**messages** table having columns **from_id, to_id, messages**.

Below is my code.

```
$chats = DB::table('users')
    ->leftJoin('messages', function($query)
    {
        $query->on('users.id', '=', 'messages.to_id')
        ->whereRaw('messages.id IN (select MAX(messages.id) from messages join users on users.id = messages.to_id  group by users.id)');
    })
    ->select('users.id as user_id', 'users.name', DB::raw('CONCAT("https://www.interwebs.co.in/puzzle/attach/", users.avatar) AS image') , 'users.mobile', 'messages.id', 'messages.from_id', 'messages.to_id', 'messages.body as message', 'messages.attachment', 'messages.seen as seen_count', 'messages.created_at')
    ->where('messages.from_id', $request->user_id)
    ->get();
```

My **messages** table is

```
| from_id  | to_id     | message  | created_at          |
| ---------| --------- | ---------| ------------------  |
| 1        | 2         | abc      | 2022-02-04 10:55:34 |
| 2        | 1         | cdef     | 2022-02-05 10:56:34 |
| 1        | 3         | defg     | 2022-02-06 10:57:34 |
| 1        | 3         | hijk     | 2022-02-07 10:58:34 |
| 1        | 2         | lmop     | 2022-02-08 10:59:34 |
```

I have tried this but it is giving me the last message of each conversation of current logged in user and not others.

Comment: Try changing `->where('messages.from_id', $request->user_id)` to `->whereColumn('messages.from_id', 'users.id')`

Comment: @yainspan no it does not work

Comment: It looks like the subquery `select MAX(messages.id) ...` in your first `LEFT JOIN` will return only one ID, which means you will be joining only one single row from the `messages` table.

Comment: @kmoser then how to get both

Comment: @ZafeerAhd What is the purpose of that `whereRaw()` to begin with? Do you really need it?

Comment: If you have something better than this, then plz tell me i want to overcome from this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the expected output with the below code.
I know there is some improvement in my code, but it is functional for now.

```
$user_id = $request->user_id;
$user_name = DB::table('users')->where('id', $user_id)->value('name');

$chats =DB::table('messages')
                    ->leftJoin('users as u1', 'messages.from_id', '=', 'u1.id')
                    ->leftJoin('users as u2', 'messages.to_id', '=', 'u2.id')
                    ->select('u1.id as user_id', 'u1.name', 'u2.name as name2', 'messages.id','messages.from_id', 
                    'messages.to_id', 'messages.body as message', 'messages.attachment', 'messages.created_at')
                    ->where('messages.from_id', $user_id)
                    ->orWhere('messages.to_id', $user_id)
                    ->latest()
                    ->get();


foreach($chats as $chat)
        {
            $chat->user_id = $chat->from_id == $user_id ? $chat->to_id : $chat->from_id;
            $chat->name = $chat->name == $user_name ? $chat->name2 : $chat->name;
        }
        $chats = $chats->unique('user_id');
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could explain how your code works. There is a bit too much code here for others to copy-paste confidently without understanding it in depth!

Answer (score 0):

I would ideally use sql to get the data. First you need to get the Max of created_at grouped by from_id and to_id, then join the results to the same table on the three fields from_id, to_id and created_at. You can also attach the users table to both from_id and to_id as aliases (from_user/to_user)...

This first query gives from_id, to_id, last_message_created_at:

```
SELECT 
    from_id, 
    to_id, 
    max(created_at) last_message_created_at 
FROM messages 
GROUP BY from_id, to_id
```

Join the results to the original messages table as follows. The final SQL would be something like this.

```
SELECT
    from_user.id,
    to_user.id,
    msgs.message,
    msgs.created_at
    # add any additional field from msgs/from_user/to_user aliases as required
FROM messages msgs
JOIN (             #join the first query above here
    SELECT 
        from_id, 
        to_id, 
        max(created_at) last_message_created_at 
    FROM messages 
    GROUP BY from_id, to_id
) last_msgs ON
    (msgs.from_id = last_msgs.from_id
    AND msgs.to_id = last_msgs.to_id
    AND msgs.created_at = last_msgs.last_message_created_at)

JOIN users from_user on from_user.id = msgs.from_id
JOIN users to_user on to_user.id = msgs.to_id
```

Use Laravel function DB::select to fetch results of the query into array. Put the above sql string into a variable `$sql`

```
$results_array = DB::select($sql)
```

Read about DB::select [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database). You can also use parameterised queries.

And [here](https://hackthestuff.com/article/how-to-execute-raw-sql-queries-in-laravel) are some examples running raw sql queries in Laravel

Comment: Hii @nazim, it is not giving me the output as expected, i want only last messages of each individual grouped conversation, but from this i am getting multiple messages from repeated users.

Comment: is there any other query i can use to get the required result

Comment: can any help me to solve this issue

Comment: The above will give a list of last messages between from_id and to_id... but if you want only the last message of `from_id` (without considering the `to_id`) then remove the `to_id` in the `GROUP BY` fields in the joined query and also remove the `to_id` in the `JOIN` condition (i.e remove the line `AND msgs.to_id = last_msgs.to_id`. You might want to update the question to show your expected result.

Comment: Hi as you said of making changes, I want last message by timestamp between two users whether it is from_id or to_id, and similarly, want last message from every user from which I had any conversation.